# Show ProgressDialog during a network call until it's FINISHED

Tags: java, android

I am **very** frustrated as I've been trying to implement a super simple loading wheel while waiting on a network call. I have searched and read dozens of SO questions and I just feel like I must be missing something, unless nobody really does what I'm trying to do. I have tried going down the `AsyncTask` route, but that's not what I want.

Let me also say that right now my app works perfectly, it's just that the transition from screen to screen appears to hang as it waits on the network. I just want a loading wheel so that in the 1-2 seconds the user knows the app is working and didn't freeze.

Here's what my current network call looks like:

```
 private static String sendDataToServer(String arg1, String arg2)
 {        
    Thread dbThread = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
             // do the call that takes a long time    
        }
    };
    dbThread.start();
    try {
        // I do this so that my program doesn't continue until
        // the network call is done and I have received the information
        // I need to render my next screen
        dbThread.join();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

Now, why can't I just add the `ProgressDialog` like this? If I do this, the progressDialog never appears.

```
 private static String sendDataToServer(String arg1, String arg2)
 {
    final ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(BaseActivity.getInstance());
    progress.setIndeterminate(true);
    progress.setMessage("Loading...");
    progress.show();

    Thread dbThread = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
             // do the call that takes a long time    
        }
    };
    dbThread.start();
    try {
        dbThread.join();
        progress.dismiss();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

I think I'm stuck because the network call needs to be on a separate thread from the UI thread, yet I don't want to continue in my application because I need the results of that call to continue. But if I do `thread.join()` I hold up everything. I thought I needed `AsyncTask` but that went downhill quickly. Here's my question on that if you're curious. 
[Android's AsyncTask: multiple params, returning values, waiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153919/androids-asynctask-multiple-params-returning-values-waiting)

How the heck to I just show a loading dialog while this call happens without proceeding through the rest of my application?

**EDIT**

Here's my `AsyncTask` attempt.

```
private class PostToFile extends AsyncTask<PostToFile, Void, Void>{
    private String functionName;
    private ArrayList<NameValuePair> postKeyValuePairs;
    private String result = "";

    public PostToFile(String function, ArrayList<NameValuePair> keyValuePairs){
        functionName= function;
        postKeyValuePairs = keyValuePairs;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(BaseActivity.getInstance(), "Loading", "Please wait...", true, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(PostToFile... params) {                       
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(FUNCTION_KEYWORD, functionName));
        for (int i = 0; i < postKeyValuePairs.size(); i++)            {
            nameValuePairs.add(postKeyValuePairs.get(i));
        }

        try{
            // ***do the POST magic.***
            result = response.toString();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
             // clean up my mess
        }

        return null;
    }

    private String getResult(){
        return result; // can I use this somehow???
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
 }
```

And when I use it:

```
        new PostToPHP(FUNCTION_NAME, postPairings){
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                try
                {
                    if (result != null && !result.startsWith("null"))
                    {
                        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                        parseData(jArray);
                    }
                }
                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    Log.e(Constants.LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                }
            };
        }.execute()
```

The problem is, I have a couple of these calls back to back, and they're each dependent on each other. So the first one starts, and the second one starts **immediately** after the first one starts, but **before** the first one is **finished**. So I get erroneous behavior. How can I start the second call only after the first is completely done?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will work, I haven't tested, but you can try:

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private int flag;


    public MyTask(int flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        switch (flag) {
            case 1:
                return doNetworking1();
            break;
            case 2:
                return doNetworking2();
            break;
            case 3:
                return doNetworking3();
            break;
            default:
                return doNetworking1();

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //show progress dialog
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        //hide progress dialog
        switch (flag) {
            case 1: //do something with result
                new MyTask(2).execute();
                break;
            case 2: //do other stuff
                new MyTask(3).execute();
                break;
            case 3: //do event more stuff
                break;
            default:
                //do something
        }
    }
}
```

and usage:

```
new MyTask(1).execute();
```

Comment: Here's the link to my question. Basically I don't know how to implement it, because I want data to be returned to me as a `String` at the end of the network call. And I also don't know how to put everything in my `onPostExecute()` as I feel it would basically be the rest of my application. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153919/androids-asynctask-multiple-params-returning-values-waiting

Comment: AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> - these are the types of arguments that are used inside AsyncTask. doInBackground method returns object of class `Result`  , and onPostExecute() receives object of class `Result` as a parameter.

Comment: But then if I do a `get()` to get the result it hangs and defeats the purpose of `AsyncTask` right?

Comment: 1. onPreExecute(); 2. doInBackgroud(); 3. onPostExecute(). When you do get() nothing freezes, cause you are doing it in doInBackground() method. When the method finishes it returns result to onPostExecute().

Comment: But when I do `new AsynTaskObject(params).execute()` it will start and then the next line is immediately executed before the execute is NECESSARILY finished. I don't want to move on until I **know** `execute()` is finished. And I know "just put it in onPostExecute" but that doesn't make sense to me. I am trying to build a module that handles my network calls, and I can't just dump everything (basically the rest of my app) in onPostExecute.

Comment: my example of AsyncTask launches next AsyncTask in onPostExecute(), so  theoretically it should work as you plan it to work. Or you can try to explain your problem in more details so we could try to find out solution for it :)

Comment: Ok, I've updated my question to include my AsyncTask implementation. Hopefully you can see something I'm missing. I appreciate the help!!

Answer (score 1):

In cases of network connections I would use `IntentService` instead of `AsyncTask`.

For example create IntentServices for network connection:

```
 public class NetworkCallIntentService extends IntentService {
    public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.yourpackage:NETWORK_CALL_BROADCAST";
    public static final String RESULT = "com.yourpackage:NETWORK_CALL_RESULT";

    public NetworkCallIntentService() {
        super(NetworkCallIntentService.class.getSimpleName());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // get data from intent if needed
        // do the call that takes long time  
        // send broadcast when done
        Intent intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        intent.putExtra(RESULT, "some_result");//and more results
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

Next, start that service from activity, show progress dialog and move code responsible for showing next screen to `BroadcastReceiver#onReceive()` method:

```
 public class SomeActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //start service
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, NetworkCallIntentService.class);
        //put extras into intent if needed
        //serviceIntent.putExtra("some_key", "some_string_value");
        startService(serviceIntent);
        //here just show progress bar/progress dialog
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(mNetworkCallReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(NetworkCallIntentService.BROADCAST_ACTION));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).unregisterReceiver(mNetworkCallReceiver);
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver mNetworkCallReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //hide progress bar/progress dialog
            //here get results from intent extras
            String result = intent.getStringExtra(NetworkCallIntentService.RESULT);
            //process results and continue program(go to next screen, show error message etc.)
        }

    }

}
```

Declare service in manifest file:

```
<service
    android:name="com.yourpackage.DownloadSvtValuesIntentService"
    android:exported="false" >
</service>
```